Terraform aws_s3_bucket_lifecycle_configuration failing to delete contents of S3 folder
I have an S3 bucket that is created via Terraform, as well as a lifecycle policy to expire everything under athena_results/ after 3 days. My code is below. The problem I'm experiencing is that this lifecycle policy isn't deleting the data under athena_results/ after 3 days. I'm curious what I'm doing. Is there something wrong or missing from my config? I've checked the docs, Google, and SO and I'm not finding anything to help.
I'm confused why this lifecycle rule wouldn't be cleaning up my Athena results. Thank you in advance if you have any ideas!
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "arapbi" {
  bucket = "arapbi"

  tags = {
    Name = "ARAPBI"
  }
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_lifecycle_configuration" "arapbi" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.arapbi.id

  rule {
    id     = "Lifecycle"
    status = "Enabled"

    filter {
      object_size_greater_than = "0"
      prefix                   = "athena_results/"
    }


    expiration {
      days = 3
    }

    noncurrent_version_expiration {
      noncurrent_days = 1
    }
  }
}


Do you need that object_size_greater_than = "0" there? I would test without it see if does what is supposed to

If you look at the examples you need to use the and to filter on more than one attribute. This is documented in the Examples
resource "aws_s3_bucket_lifecycle_configuration" "arapbi" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.arapbi.id

  rule {
    id     = "Lifecycle"
    status = "Enabled"

    filter {
      and {
        prefix                   = "athena_results/"
        object_size_greater_than = "0"
      }
    }


    expiration {
      days = 3
    }

    noncurrent_version_expiration {
      noncurrent_days = 1
    }
  }
}

As documented in the filter block config. You must specify exactly one filter

The filter configuration block must either be specified as the empty
configuration block (filter {}) or with exactly one of prefix, tag,
and, object_size_greater_than or object_size_less_than specified.


From reading the documentation: and- (Optional) Configuration block used to apply a logical AND to two or more predicates. I will assume if the and is not used the predicates in the filter block will apply with an or logic, and more files would be deleted than expected ...

I just tested this and I get an error: api error MalformedXML: The XML you provided was not well-formed or did not validate against our published schema ... terraform applies successfully without the and

Seems the problem is object_size_greater_than = "0" if I change the 0 to a 1 it applies correctly

Thank you for your help with this. The changes you suggested are deployed via Terraform. I'm waiting to see if the lifecycle rule deletes the objects as expected. Assuming it does, I'll update and accept this answer.
